# .NET 6 TestServer cannot resolve Controller

Tags: .net, testing, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 minimal API, and I'm using `WebApplicationFactory<T>` for integration testing. Usually, I have something roughly like this in my tests:

```
using TestServer server = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().Server;
using HttpClient client = server.CreateClient();
// ... do stuff with the client
```

However, I would like to also test my controller directly (primarily so that I can use the debugger within the controller itself during the tests), after getting an instance of it with all the DI goodness baked in from the factory, but it throws an exception when I try to resolve my controller, like this:

```
using TestServer server = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().Server;

// throws InvalidOperationException : No service for type 'MyController' has been registered.
var controller = server.Services.GetRequiredService<MyController>();
```

Why is this happening, and is there a way to fix it?

### EDIT:

Of course, I have a line in `Program.cs` like this:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

...and my API starts up correctly and the controller in question works in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but this worked:

### 1 - Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
```

### 2 - Add controllers as services

```
using TestServer server = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
        }
    })
    .Server;

// now this works
var controller = server.Services.GetRequiredService<MyController>();
```